# CSS/Javascript issue causing items not to display after hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am experiencing an issue here but I dont know where to begin looking to fix it. I dont see any issues code wise but there has to be something i am missing that is causing this: Can anyone provide any assistance as for a clue what might be causing this:

https://enviroworkshops.com/training/us-remediation-presenters-training-session/

Issue: when hovering over some of the items on the page some of the speakers will go completely blank.

Comment: Open your browser console or use the dev tools, that would be a good place to look.

Comment: I notice when you hover over items then hold still, some of the flickering is in sync with the jquery slide animation in your sidebar. Try disabling the sidebar and see if you still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinkering around in chrome dev tools, it seems that the below two properties affecting the presenters_list_item div are to blame.

```
.workshops_list_item:hover, 
.presenters_list_item:hover, 
.organizations_list_item:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
```

After deleting them *(or in my case, disabling them via dev tools)* it fixes the wonky disappearing act you were experiencing.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly it. I could not seem to track it down and I tried a number of things.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `overflow: visible` to `.presenters_list_item` class, it fixes the problem

Comment: Thank you, I was able to replicate this in the inspector but adding it to the stylesheet didnt do anything to fix it. The solution above actually fixed it and didnt affect anything else.